# Issue when performing auto-flash on ESP32-S3 with CH340G

Tags: esp32, programmer

I'm designing a PCB with ESP32 and CH340G. When attempting to perform autoflash, I encounter an error: "A fatal error has occurred - Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received".The EN and BOOT outputs are being rapidly activated and deactivated. I am attaching images of what's happening,[image: EN INPUT] [image: EN INPUT ZOOM] [image: PROGRAMMER] [image]

Comment: Using the "BOOT" and "EN" buttons works well for flashing.

Comment: you should have 4.7K pull-down on DTR to request more current from the USB.  this may be unrelated.

Comment: VCC of CH340 should be connect to 5V (or VBUS) instead of 3.3V. BTW, the V3 output of CH340 can only provide 100mA 3.3V output which may not be sufficient to drive an ESP32 when WiFi is in use.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I saw that it was a problem with the footprint of transistors Q1 and Q2.